# bash is crashing on cygwin add_item ("\??\C:\cygwin", "/", ...)

Tags: windows, cygwin

I am trying to run applications on windows cluster. I am getting random crashes like bellow but most times it works.
I suspected that it was [famous forking issue](https://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures), but cygwin's rebase did not help.

Thank you for suggestions.

```
2 [main] bash 12840 C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??\C:\cygwin", "/", ...) failed, errno 1
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
002868A8  6102F97B  (002868A8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
00286B98  6102F97B  (6119FE20, 00008000, 00000000, 611A1C8F)
00287BC8  6100652C  (611DF498, 00287BF4, 00000000, 60FE000C)
00287BE8  61006568  (611DF498, 00289C10, 00000001, 0003000A)
0028AC28  610917E4  (60FE000C, 20000C08, 0028ACF8, 61083290)

0028AC58  610D40FF  (004C46B0, 01D05699, 004657E0, 612729D4)
208979 [main] bash 12840 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

- cygwin 6.1
- windows server 2008 R2 Ent

I have got explanation to the error from [cygwin support guys](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00144.html)(Thanks to Corinna):

> That's not a rebase problem.  It's apparently a concurrency problem of
>   sorts.  While pulling up the per-user shared memory region, two or
>   more processes are trying to set up the same mount points.
>
> This is not supposed to happen.  Only the first process actually
>   *creating* the per-user shared memory is supposed to create the mount points.  The OS tells a process if it created or just opened a shared
>   memory region, but for some reason both processes seem to think they
>   created the shmem region and one of them then stumbles of the EPERM
>   condition trying to create the root mount point twice.
>
> But it is still leave problem the original problem.

Comment: Cygwin does some pretty funky stuff.  It might not be compatible with clustering.  But have you checked the list of [incompatible applications](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda)?